# Theme/plugin customization: Is it possible to create 1 shared user profile that ties together and combines user profiles from separate plugins/themes?

Tags: wordpress, user-interface, plugins, wordpress-theming, customization

Disclaimer: I am below even a beginner level of coding/promgramming. I have created a wordpress website using the listingpro business directory THEME (includes a consumer login for customers). I also have a subdomain using the Dokan multivendor marketplace PLUGIN (includes a consumer login for customers).

Currently, my website visitors will create two separate logins by using my site: one for the main domain, the other for the subdomain.

I had to create it this way because I do not have the knowledge to create a combination directory and ecommerce marketplace, and could not find a pre-existing commercial option.

To make for a better user experience, I would like for my site users to be able to create one login that works for both domain and subdomain, linking them together somehow.

A truly beautiful possibility would be to completely merge the theme and the plugin functionalities, but even my beginner knowledge makes me think that is impossible or crazy expensive.

Is there any way to accomplish my desired task?

Comment: You might be able to achieve this using a multisite structure and implementing single sign on. So user logged in on your main domain (listing site) will no longer need to login back to your marketplace